# Монтирование директорий в запущенный контейнер Docker

Tags: администрирование, docker

При запуске контейнера мы можем примонтировать к нему директорию системы-хоста, о чем написано в [документации](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

Но как нам монтировать директорию в уже запущенный контейнер? Можно сделать это средствами Docker? Видел только решение с использованием [стороннего кода](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/)

Comment: а зачем вам это нужно? какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Jérôme Petazzoni работает на компанию Docker думаю, что если у него этот способ описан как единственное решение, то средствами  Docker это не сделать.

Comment: не вижу, где по ссылке есть хоть строчка «стороннего кода». там предлагается именно монтирование каталога внутрь контейнера. ну, да, непосредственно в программе *docker* это не реализовано. можете сами добавить, если отсутствие такой редкой возможности вас смущает.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman допустим, забыл примонтировать директорию при запуске, чтобы не останавливать контейнер, хочу монтировать на "горячую".

Comment: @while1pass на production вы не должны это делать руками, а на своей машине легче перезапустить контейнер.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman разумно, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно стандартными средствами смонтировать том данных к запущенному контейнеру нельзя. Многое зависит от задач для которых хотите использовать том.

Но, можно сделать том данных отдельным контейнером, а потом смонтировать его в нужном контейнере хоть через тот же sshfs.